# Restrict access to web application

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have create a two Azure Web APP (Front & Back).

I am able to access the Front web app from the public  But I am also able to access the backend web app from the public.

I want to restrict the access to backend app, and allow some Azure Service such as Azure DevOps

What is the best and less expensive technology to do this , implement Azure Front Door, App Gateway , WAF ?

thanks, regards Quentin

Answer (score 0):

You may leverage Private Endpoints.

Private Endpoint for your Azure Web App to allow clients located in your private network to securely access the app over Private Link. In this case, the Private Endpoint uses an IP address from your Azure VNet address space. Network traffic between a client on your private network and the Web App traverses over the VNet and a Private Link on the Microsoft backbone network, eliminating exposure from the public Internet.

Main uses for this feature:

- Secure your Web App by configuring the Private Endpoint, eliminating
  public exposure.
- Securely connect to Web App from on-premises
  networks that connect to the VNet using a VPN or ExpressRoute private
  peering.

For DevOps access:
You must create two records in your Azure DNS private zone or your custom DNS server.

**Name  Type    Value**

mywebapp.privatelink.azurewebsites.net   **A**   PrivateEndpointIP

mywebapp.scm.privatelink.azurewebsites.net   **A**   PrivateEndpointIP

Kindly see this doc ([private endpoints for Azure WebApp)](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

App Services access restrictions are your friend :) Either IP-based and/or based on Service Endpoints
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features#access-restrictions

Comment: I don’t understand your question

Comment: i can add domain like management.core.windows.net in IP restrection ?